# Change a certain variable to true from a provider

Tags: angular, angular-services

In my ionic application I want to add a certain product to my cart and then list all product who have been bought by the user in a page.

I have already implemented a provider.

Service file ProductProvider

```
load() {
    return this.products = [
      { id: 1, name: "McFlurry", price: 2, enseigne: "McDonalds", inBag: false },
      { id: 2, name: "Potatoes", price: 3, enseigne: "McDonalds", inBag: false },
      { id: 3, name: "BigMac", price: 4, enseigne: "KFC", inBag: false },
      { id: 4, name: "Nuggets", price: 3, enseigne: "KFC", inBag: false }
    ];
}
```

Function to add the item (I got those values by navparams from the preceding page)

```
addToBasket(name: string, price: number) {
    this.event.publish("cart:updated", this.count);
    productProvider.setInbag(true)
    this.viewCtrl.dismiss();
}
```

I don't know how I can select a certain object from my array to set the inBag variable to true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you will have to pass the name into the productProvider.setInbag(true) function:

e.g.: Service file ProductProvider

```
setInbag(name: string, inbag: boolean) {
  var product = this.products.find(f => f.name === name);
  product.inBag = inbag;

}
```

the find method exists on arrays and will return the first item where the predicate (f => f.name === name) is true.

On a side note:

I see that your products have an id property. You should rather use that to pass the selected product around instead of it's name. Products might have the same name for different enseigne's.

Comment: Thank you that's exactly what i want. And i should use id rather than name.